# Adding variables in Stata and then dividing by a number is giving unexpected results

Tags: stata

I am trying to calculate z-scores by creating a variable D from 3 other variables, namely A, B, and C. I am trying to generate D as : D= (A-B)/C but for some reason when I do it, it produces very large numbers. When I did just (A-B) it did not get what it should have when I calculated by hand, instead of -2, I for -105.66.

Variable A is 'long' and variable B is 'float', I am not sure if this is the reason? My stata syntax is:

```
gen zscore= (height-avheight)/meansd
```

did not work.

Comment: Provide us the sample data

Comment: There is no reason why (value - mean) should not be of the order of 100; that depends on the variability of the data and the units of measurement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing scalars and variables. Here's a solution (chop off the first four lines and replace `x` by `height` to fit the calculation into your code):

```
// example data
clear
set obs 50
gen x = runiform()

// summarize
qui su x
// store scalars
sca de mu = r(mean)
sca de sd = r(sd)

// z-score
gen zx = (x - mu) / sd
su zx
```

`x` and its z-score `zx` are variables that take many values, whereas `mu` and `sd` are constants. You might code constants in Stata by using scalars or macros.

Comment: I don't see that this answers the question but in any case the `scalar` statements are not needed here. After `summarize x` you can `generate zx = (x - r(mean)) / r(sd)`.

Comment: Correct, you could skip them and collapse the syntax, but the question seemed to imply that intermediate values are of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to get, but I will use the auto data from Stata to explain.  This is basic stuff in Stata.  Say I want to test that the price=3

```
sysuse auto
sum price
#return list which is optional command
scalar myz=(3-r(mean))/r(sd) #r(mean) and r(sd) gives the mean and sd of price, if that is given you can simply enter the value for that
dis myz
-2.0892576
```

So, z value is -2.09 here.